# template instead of templateUrl in angularjs and Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-routing, route-provider

I am using `AngularJs` in `Asp.Net mvc 4`. I would like to use the template in `$routeProvider` instead of `templateUrl`

I wan to use this one

```
$routeProvider.when('/url', { template: '/view/page.html',controller: 'myCtrl' })
```

Instead of this one

```
$routeProvider.when('/url', { templateUrl: '/view/page',controller: 'myCtrl' })
```

I don't want to create methods in controller(that only contains return PartialView()) every time I need to implement a page. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want the content within the `/view/page.html` to be displayed or simply you want to show like `/view/page.html` printed

Comment: Mixing server side and client side routing, or even trying to will lead to a lot of pain. 

You may need to revisit some angular js fundamental - specifically to understand that there is no server side dependency when working within angular.

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan I want to implement the content in /view/page.html.

Comment: I am not trying to mix their routing, i am just trying not to use any web controllers just to render the page

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to load the html template without having to use a controller.

To do this just create a new folder in your web project called Templates and then in your RouteConfig.cs add a line to ignore this folder like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Templates/{filename}.html");
    ...
}
```

Then in angular you can use the template url and get your file:

```
$routeProvider.when('/url', { templateUrl: '/templates/page.html',controller: 'myCtrl' })
```

Angular will be able to use your template and you won't need a controller.